# Java set different IP address on DatagramSocket

Tags: java, networking, udp

I want to simulate a network on my computer.
I want to send each packet with a different IP address.
How do I set the IP address on the Socket?

For example, I want to set my IP address is 192.168.1.1 or 192.168.1.1/24.
How do I do?

I only know how to set the port number.

`private static DatagramSocket socket;
socket = new DatagramSocket(1024);`

Can I use
`DatagramSocket(int port, InetAddress laddr)`
to initial my socket?

if yes, what should I input in the parameter "laddr"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you mean set the source IP address - you can't.  A UDP socket is bound to a particular IP interface (or interfaces) on your computer.  The IP interface is what 'has' the address. A program using IP sockets only gets to choose which existing interface to use.

Note that even if you could arbitrarily set the source-address field in an outgoing datagram, there would be no simple way to receive any reply - because there's nothing on your computer responding to your chosen address (there is no IP interface at that address).

If you want to simulate having different IP addresses in a program,, you'll need to simulate IP. That would involve using raw sockets, but there does not seem to be a Java implementation for that.

Comment: In Class DatagramSocket, there is an initial of DatagramSocket is  `DatagramSocket(int port, InetAddress laddr)`. Is "InetAddress" an IP address? If I want to put "192.168.1.1" in there. How do I do?

Comment: That's the interface you want to bind the socket to - the interface is identified by its IP address.  You can only pick existing interfaces (default is "all").  On Linux, 'ifconfig` lists your interfaces; on Windows it's `'ipconfig'. To make an InetAddress, see the [documentation page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html) - too many options to list here.